# Adding custom column to SAPUI5 smart - columnKey error

Tags: sapui5

I have a XML view with a smart table binded to an oData service. For this smart table I want to add a custom column for `erdat` as described in the [SAPUI5 sample](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/sdk/#/entity/sap.ui.comp.smarttable.SmartTable/sample/sap.ui.comp.sample.smarttable.mtableCustom/code).

Code from the XML view:

```
<smartTable:SmartTable id="smartTable0" entitySet="<my_entity_set>" enableAutoBinding="true" beforeRebindTable="onBeforeRebindTable"
    tableType="ResponsiveTable" useExportToExcel="true" useTablePersonalisation="true" showRowCount="true" showFullScreenButton="true"
    class="sapUiResponsiveContentPadding" exportType="UI5Client" demandPopin="true">
    <smartTable:layoutData>
        <FlexItemData growFactor="1" baseSize="0%"/>
    </smartTable:layoutData>
    <Table alternateRowColors="true" fixedLayout="false" growing="true" growingScrollToLoad="true" growingThreshold="20">
        <columns>
            <Column width="200px" hAlign="Begin">
                <customData>
                    <core:CustomData key="p13nData" value="\{'columnKey': 'erdat', 'leadingProperty': 'erdat', 'columnIndex': '0'}"/>
                </customData>
                <Text text="Erdat"/>
            </Column>
        </columns>
        <items>
            <ColumnListItem>
                <cells>
                    <Text text="{path: 'erdat'}"/>
                </cells>
            </ColumnListItem>
        </items>
    </Table>
</smartTable:SmartTable>
```

Without the custom column the smart table displays the data as expected. When I add the custom column I get an error:

> Uncaught (in promise) The table instance contains some columns for which a columnKey is provided, some for which a columnKey is not provided.

The table shows the column headers only, but no data. I have tried several combinations with and without `columnKey` or `leadingProperty` but without success. The field `erdat` is included in the oData service.

Web search didn't provide a solution for me. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I replace `'` with `"` and vice versa in `<core:CustomData value=...>` it's working as intended. Should have typed exactly as in the example...